# Why isn't child component rendering when testing with React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing UI unit tests using Jest/Testing Library.

I have a `DashboardLayout` component that returns

```
return (
    <DashboardLayoutRoot sx={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
      <DashboardNavbar
        onSidebarMobileOpen={(): void => setIsSidebarMobileOpen(true)}
      />
      <DashboardSidebar
        onMobileClose={(): void => setIsSidebarMobileOpen(false)}
        openMobile={isSidebarMobileOpen}
      />
      <DashboardLayoutWrapper>
        <DashboardLayoutContainer>
          <DashboardLayoutContent>{children}</DashboardLayoutContent>
        </DashboardLayoutContainer>
      </DashboardLayoutWrapper>
    </DashboardLayoutRoot>
  );
```

DashboardNavBar:

```
<DashboardNavbarRoot {...other}>
      <Toolbar sx={{ minHeight: 64 }}>
        <Hidden lgUp>
          <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={onSidebarMobileOpen}>
            <MenuIcon fontSize="small" data-testid="sidebar-icon" />
          </IconButton>
        </Hidden>
```

As you can see I set testid in MenuIcon.

However, when rendering in test, getByTestId fails.

```
// skip setup above

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DashboardLayout />
    </Provider>,
  );
 const sidebarIcon = screen.getByTestId('sidebar-icon');

  expect(sidebarIcon).toBeVisible();
```

I do set up everything correctly, like mock router, Provider etc.

Why is this happening?

Should I just render DashboardNavbar by itself? (not sure if this would be good UI unit test though)

Comment: Perhaps it's because it's inside `<Hidden>`?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to mock the child component and test for mocked component

```
// skip setup above
jest.mock('./MenuIcon', () => ({ MenuIcon : () => 'mocked menu icon' }));

const container = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DashboardLayout />
    </Provider>,
  );
 

  expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div>
        mocked menu icon
      </div>
    `);
```

Comment: thank you for your asnwer. I think it is close, but not quite the case for my code above. Would you be able to write another mocking if you have one in mind?